# How to consume a C# class from C++/CLI using PIMPL

Tags: .net, interop, c++-cli, pimpl-idiom

I need to consume a C# class from an unmanaged application. Say I have the following C# class:

```
public class Managed
{
    public void Subcribe(int handler)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Then I create the following C++/CLI class:

```
/// Header
class Mixed
{
public:
    void Subscribe(int handler);
private:
    class MixedImp;
    MixedImp* m_implementation;
}

/// CPP
ref class MixedImp
{
public:
    void Subscribe(int handler)
    {
        m_accessor->Subscribe(handler);
    }
private:
    Managed^ m_accessor;
}

Mixed::Subcribe(int handler)
{
    m_implementation->Subcribe(handler)
}
```

When doing this I get a pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed so I'm not getting something. I'm not a natural unmanaged developer so forgive me if the question is somewhat silly :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <vcclr.h>


class Mixed
{
public:
  void Subscribe(int handler)
  {
    m_accessor->Subscribe(handler);
  }
private:
  gcroot<Managed^> m_accessor;
};
```